# Artifacts when capturing bitmap from Viewport3D?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, windows-10, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm trying capture an image from a Viewport3D element in a WPF app. It works fine when the 3D models in the viewport are relatively close to the camera, but if I zoom out then artifacts start to show up. It seems like some kind of perspective thing, but I'm not sure why. The model seems to flatten out the more I zoom.

I'm using [Helix Toolkit](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit) as the framework wrapping the 3D stuff, so my first try was to capture using `Viewport3DHelper.SaveBitmap()`, after that I tried using a more generic `UIElement` approach using a `RenderTargetBitmap` and writing it to disk via a `PngBitmapEncoder`. These yielded the same results.

My camera in question is a `PerspectiveCamera`, where I set the position, look direction, up direction, and the far plane distance (which I hadn't changed until trying to solve this).

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image: Zoomed in]
[image: Zoomed out]

EDIT: Note  this that issue does not appear when using an `OrthographicCamera`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reduce far plane distance or increase near plane distance

Comment: Dang, I should've just messed with the near plane distance as well. Thanks, you're the man.